How to set Audio from the Kameleo API?
If you interested in setting the Audio from the Kameleo API by using various programming languages, the resulting examples are below:

Javascript:
const createProfileRequest = BuilderForCreateProfile
    .forBaseProfile(baseProfileId)
    .set_audio('noise') \ # Options: ('noise', 'block', 'off')
    .build();
const profile = await client.createProfile({ body: createProfileRequest });

Python:
create_profile_request = BuilderForCreateProfile \
    .for_base_profile(base_profiles[0].id) \
    .set_audio('noise') \ # Options: ('noise', 'block', 'off')
    .build()
profile = client.create_profile(body=create_profile_request)

